# Monitor shell script with monit

Tags: java, bash, shell, monit

I have a shell script that spawns a java process that I'd like to wrap in a wrapper for use with monit.

I've tried the monit recommendation of

```
#!/bin/bash

name=`basename $1`
case $2 in
    start)
       echo $$ > /var/run/service.pid;
       exec 2>&1 $1 1>/var/log/$name.stdout
       ;;
     stop)
       kill `cat /var/run/service.pid` ;;
     *)
       echo "usage: <path to app> {start|stop}" ;;
 esac
```

Where I'd use it like `wrapper.sh /usr/sbin/cmd start`

When I do this, I see 2 procesess spun up. One is the exec in the wrapper, and the other is my java process.

However, the pid of `$$` is that of the /usr/sbin wrapper and not of the actual java process. So if I "stop" the service or kill that pid, then the java process gets orphaned.

On the other hand, if I run `/usr/sbin/cmd` in the foreground and then kill it, it does kill the child process.

Comment: If you `exec` the java process as the script aove dows, said java process will replace the shell process running the wrapper and thus will keep the same PID.  Your problem is that the java process further forks other processes.

Comment: Thanks, this was the key I needed. In the /sbin command that execs my java process I needed to also add `exec` before the java invocation so that it would also use the same pid. Now in my sbin wrapper i have `exec java ...` and it all works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't grab the pid before you run the command, but you can use `$!`. Also, I would suggest you use `nohup`. So something like

```
nohup $1 > /var/log/$name.stdout 2>&1 &
echo $! > /var/run/service.pid
```